# How to change the value on tab press in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here in my code there are two tabs and  one button .
1 tab value is coming from array(props) and populating and getting the sum and displaying in below button.
2nd tab has a input field where I am entering any value and that value am displaying in below button.
now if I go to 2nd tab then only that value should display which I'll enter else 0 and again if I come back to first tab that sum value should come which is coming from the array .
All this value should display in single button .
/////////////////////////////////////////

1 tab , vale is populating with checkbox and ono checkbox click value is adding and on un check its getting minus .
2 tab its a input field where user can enter any value .
but there is one button .
I am trying to do ,that if I come to first tab value in button should come specific , and if I changed to 2 nd tab value should come 0 by default and what I enter in input that only come in button.
I tried something please help . 
https://xd.adobe.com/view/d733da48-5d0c-47ca-7ded-6fc8f0f609cf-a102/screen/37cb15c6-b56a-4b98-8612-e9b86d0dd34c/Android-Mobile-147/?fullscreen

```
// Below is array value 
       financialTransactionDetail: Array(3)
        0:
        AdjustedAmount: "0"
        NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
        TransactionAmount: 1050
        1:
        AdjustedAmount: "0"
        NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
        TransactionAmount: 1050

        2:
        AdjustedAmount: "0"
        NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
        Status: "Unpaid"
        TransactionAmount: 1050

       this.state={
       invoice_specific:0,
          as_hoc:0
          }
           handleChangeTab = (key,value) => {
          console.log("value ",key);

        this.setState({
          invoice_specific:  key === 'SPECIFIC' ? !this.state.invoice_specific : this.state.invoice_specific,
          as_hoc:  key === 'Ad_Hoc' ? !this.state.as_hoc : this.state.notification.as_hoc,


        })

      }
      render(){
      this.state.checked.map((value, index) => { if(value) 
          { invoice_specific += financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail[index].TransactionAmount; } });
    retun(

           <Tabs>
                      <Tab heading="INVOICE SPECIFIC" 
                        onPress={() => this.handleChangeTab('SPECIFIC')}>

                      { !_.isEmpty(financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail) && financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.map(
                        (data, index) => {
                          const formatedate = data.DueDate;
                          const formateDate = formatedate.split(' ')[0];
                          return(
                            <View key={index} style={{flexDirection:'row', padding:10, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between',backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                          <View style={{paddingRight:10, marginRight:10}}>
                          <CheckBox style={styles.checkBox} color="#00678f" checked={this.state.checked[index]} onPress={() =>this.handleChange(index)}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1, padding:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:3}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
                              {!this.state.checked[index] && <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{paddingBottom:10, paddingRight:5}}/>}
                              <SmallText text={`Due by ${(formateDate)}`} style={{paddingBottom:10}}/>
                            </View>
                            {this.state.checked[index] && 
                            <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                              </RegularText>
                            }
                          </View>
                        </View>
                          )
                        }
                      )
                      }

                      </Tab>
                      <Tab heading="AD-HOC">
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'column', padding:10,  backgroundColor:'#fff', minHeight:deviceHeight }}>
                          <RegularText text="Enter Specific Amount to pay" style={{paddingBottom:5}} textColor="#959595"/>
                          <View>
                            <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                              <Input
                                  autoFocus={true}
                                  onPress={() => this.handleChangeTab('Ad_Hoc')}
                                />
                            </Item>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </View>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>

            <View style={{bottom:0,position:'absolute', width: '100%'}}>
              <Button full onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('PaymentOptionsContainer',invoice_specific)}>
                <Text>Receive Payment ({invoice_specific})</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
```

Comment: Its very difficult to understand your question, can u please edit it better?, my understanding is that, on click of second tab, the value should be 0. is that it?

Comment: let me edit my question , sorry for confusion

Comment: Edited , please help